# CSS3 Issue with transition

Tags: html, css

So I am having trouble getting the transition to work here, on hover works to switch the images, and I have used this transition another site and works just fine when used on the same machine and browser however on this site I am building currently the transition is not having it.... Here is the HTML& CSS

```
<div class="grid_4">
<h3 class="foot">
Say Hello! 
</h3>
<h3 class="descripfoot">
<div class="grid_2">
<a class="testicon" title="flickr Link" align="left" href="http://www.flickr.com"></a>
</div>
    some description text goes hereeeee

</h3>
</div>


a.testicon
{
    background: url("../images/testicon.png");
    width:140px;
    height: 140px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    display: inline-block;

 }

a.testicon:hover,a.testicon:focus,a.testicon:active
{
width:140px;
height: 140px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    display: inline-block;
   -webkit-transition: background .3s linear 0s;
-moz-transition: background .3s linear 0s;
background: url("../images/testicon2.png");
}
```

Comment: it is workin perfectly, did you cleaned up your browser cache>?

Comment: You know, it's funny. It "works" at jsfiddle sometimes, but not all the time http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/LWsVt/. I clicked the link I just posted, and it didn't work. But I refreshed that page then it did - some sort of browser/cache issue I'd suppose

Comment: Its some kind of awkward browser caching apparently. I keep clearing history and cookies yet the problem exists. It works on other machines. Thanks guys!

Comment: You're using the same URL for your placeholder images. These could be cached, so it might think that they are both the same image, and the transition doesn't happen because it doesn't see a change.

Comment: Also, the first time you hover over the image, the browser will request the hover image, so you'll see a "flickering" as it is loaded, but subsequent hover/blur events should cause the transition to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/LWsVt/2/

```
a.testicon
{
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 200px 200px;
    width:140px;
    height: 140px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s linear 0s; /* obviously declare all vendor prefixes here */
 }

a.testicon:hover,a.testicon:focus,a.testicon:active
{
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400);
    outline:none;
}​
```

Note I simplified the CSS and got rid of redundant property declarations.